# In HTML, how to retrieve data stored in php variables that are read in jQuery's Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have written a website (in A.php) with a few tabs, each of which, when clicked on, retrieves multiple pictures data from another php file (= B.php) using jQuery's ajax and displays them. Those pictures are objects of a class (declared in C.php) and each picture has unique name, date when it was taken, and place where it was taken. They are all written in PHP and stored in php variables. Initially, when the data are asynchronously retrieved and the pictures are displayed, they only show the pictures and the name of them, but not the date and place. I want to make each picture show, using modal, the date and place only when they are clicked on.

I got the modal part working, but it is currently blank as I am not sure how to approach this problem and show the date and place for each photo.

Below is part of A.php where modal is, in which I want to show date and place of each photo:

```
<div class="modal">
    <!-- Close modal process here (omitted)-->
    <div class="date-and-place">
        <?php
           /*I am not sure what to write in here*/
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is B.php:

```
/*This is the data displayed on the screen after the tab is clicked on, 
  using ajax call from A.php
  This will only show the pictures and the name*/
<?php
    require_once("C.php");
?>
<div class="pictureData">
    <!--loop through an array containing all picture objects-->
    <?php foreach($pictures as $picture): ?>
        <img class="picture"><?php echo $picture->getPicture() ?>
        <h3 class="pictureName"><?php echo $picture->getName() ?></h3>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

And finally C.php:

```
/*This file only has class and object definitions*/
<?php
    class Pics{
        private $name;
        private $imgURL;
        private $date;
        private $place;
    }
    /*There is constructor here, and each object is given name,              
      imgURL, date and place when created(omitted)*/
    /*and there is getter functions for each as well (omitted)*/
    /*Store each object data in an array*/
    $pictures = array($object1, $object2, ....);
?>
```

How could you possibly show the specific photo's date and place information (only show the date and place of the picture clicked on)?
Any help would be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance!

Comment: Well you've got that code that dumps out the picture names; why not just do exactly the same thing (in B.php) for the other information?

Comment: Really not clear what the specific problem is in making it work. What modal? how is it initialized? Look into using data attributes

Comment: One way to do this is to add the date/place data to the image's `<h3>` like this: `<h3 data-date="2012-03-07" data-place="Town">...</h3>`. You can easily read back this information using basic jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd take an entirely different approach:

1. send complete image data using `json_encode($pictures)`
2. client-side: store image array; show images
3. on click, modal simply reads additional data from JS array

This also separates content from presentation, since B.php no longer sends HTML.

Comment: Thank you! I apologize because it seems like I confused everyone... The part I am stuck on is, I am not sure how to tell the program to show the date and place of $this image. The code in B.php only worked because I was printing all array data (except for date and place), but my problem is how you could print the data of $this picture, that has just been clicked on.

Comment: In the 3 steps you gave me, at #3 could you please tell me how you could retrieve the date/place data of the very image that is clicked on only?

Comment: Oh I actually misread your answer. I see how your method works now! Thank you very much!